# entity framework c# eager loading inherited and nested properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a following object as a model in project:

AbstractControll and AntivirusControll which inherits from AbstractControll.

```
public class AntivirusControll: AbstractControll
```

AnticvirusControll has property:

```
public List<Exclusion> Exclusions { get; set; }
```

And this part of code drives me creazy:

```
var a  = _entities.AntivirusControlls.First(m => m.Id == 1);
var b  = _entities.AbstractControlls.First(m => m.Id == 1);
```

In database AnticvirusControll has one exception,while in result of executing above code I get:
a.Exclusions - has one object ( which is great and ok ) 
b.Exclusions - has none!

How is it even called inheritance? It's not polymorphic, it's .... a bug I could tell. Lazy loading wont work in this case. 
And while asking for AbstractControlls I Can't include any property from derivered class offcourse.

Any ideas how to fix it?

--EDIT 
both classes;

```
public abstract class AbstractControll
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


public abstract class AbstractControll
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
public class AntivirusControll: AbstractControll
    {




        public class Exclusion
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            [Display(Name = "Object Type")]
            public String ObjectType { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            [Display(Name = "Object Type")]
            public String ObjectName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public ConfigurationItemDescription ExlusionCI { get; set; }
        }

        [Display(Name= "Is Antyvirus Enabled")]
        [DataMember]
        public bool? isAntyvirusEnabled { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public ConfigurationItemDescription isAntyvirusEnabledCI { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Display(Name = "Is real time protection enabled")]
        public bool? isRealTimeProtectionEnabled { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public ConfigurationItemDescription isRealTimeProtectionEnabledCI { get; set; }


        [DataMember]
        [Display(Name = "Virus definition not older than( in days)")]
        [Required]
        [Range(typeof(int),"1","365")]
        public int? VirusDefinitionNotOlderThen { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public ConfigurationItemDescription VirusDefinitionNotOlderThenCI { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Exclusion> Exclusions { get; set; }





        public AntivirusControll()
        {

            isAntyvirusEnabled = true;
            isRealTimeProtectionEnabled = true;
            VirusDefinitionNotOlderThen = 7;
            isAntyvirusEnabledCI = new ConfigurationItemDescription();
            isRealTimeProtectionEnabledCI = new ConfigurationItemDescription();
            VirusDefinitionNotOlderThenCI = new ConfigurationItemDescription();
            Exclusions = new List<Exclusion>();
        }

    }
```

--Edit 2 
Well... I wanto to clarify, what actualy I'm doing. 
I have MVC + angular Application. 
There is a document with some Controls( AbstractControll) 
Each of them is specific Type for example: Antivirus, Encryption and so on. At this point I have about 20 of them, but I will have more probably. Most of those derived classes have inner classes like Exceptions in Antivirus.
Right. 
Basicaly that's it. What is important- After getting "AbstractControll" I want to expose this object over webapi - so lazy loading is not applicable here( or maybe it could be?)
That's it. It runtime I don't know exat type of the controll, so I Can't Include Properties from for example "Antivirus", when operating on DbSet

What I have now is ugly if's block that returns propper object and includes everything, but i'm not happy about his "hack".

Comment: Very simple test: put line `b` above line `a` and debug to see what  values they hold now ;)

Comment: Id is in AbstractControll and there is no separated table for AntivirusControll -which is absolutely fine. There is also column: Discriminator, that should determine type. Exclusion has it's own table  and there is FK.

Comment: swaping lines with b and a - no change.

Comment: Could you post both classes?

Comment: `AbstractControlls` only has an ID property, therefore it can never even have the `Exclusions` property.

Comment: Yeach I can see it. It's not ok by design in my opinion. This is not Object oriented. I've seen feture requests that should solve the problem , but they are 2 years old(!) now.

Comment: Well, to be honest, it is actually the design of you models. What exactly are you trying to achieve? You should maybe edit the post and then we can help you figuring out what the best code will be.